# java request returns keyless array as strings, need to represent with realm

Tags: java, android, realm

I have a request that goes out from my Java android application that returns a response like this:

```
{  
    "data":[],
    "messages":{  
        "day_unavailable":{  
            "unavailable_days":[  
                "2018-09-24",
                "2018-09-25",
                "2018-09-26",
                "2018-09-27",
                "2018-09-28",
                "2018-09-29",
                "2018-09-30"
            ]
        }
    },
    "code":"",
    "status":"failed",
    "status_code":400
}
```

Now I have access to the messages but am struggling to convert them to realm objects.

To convert this, I first use this realm object to pick up different messages:

```
public class ChangeModelVersion extends RealmObject {

    public PaymentRequired paymentRequired;

    public DayUnavailable dayUnavailable;

    public Boolean repairsUnavailble;
}
```

The `DayUnavailable` model is here:

```
public class DayUnavailable extends RealmObject {

    public String unavailableDays;
}
```

The issue is that `unavailable_days` is not a string but an array of strings. And using `List<String>` and ArrayList both seem to cause errors.

What should I be using?

Answer (score -1):

Just use `String[]` like this:

```
public class DayUnavailable extends RealmObject {

    public String[]unavailableDays;
}
```

or if you want to use list you can parse the response manually and put the `String`s in a `List` or `Array`:

```
try {
   JSONObject response = new JSONObject (responseRaw);
   JSONObject messages = response.getJSONObject("messages");
   JSONObject day_unavailable = response.getJSONObject("day_unavailable");
   JSONArray unavailable_days = response.getJSONArray("unavailable_days");
   for(int i=0;i<unavailable_days.length();i++) {
      String unavailableDay = unavailable_days.getString(i);
      // loop and add it to array or arraylist
   }
} catch(Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```